# How to create an editable treelistview in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, blend

I need to create an editable `TreeListView` for my project.
But as far as I can see, `WPF` does not provide any type of tree list view and the ones I found online were not very informative. I want to create something using `blend` and then apply that to my `WPF` project.

Does any one have any ideas about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Editable as in? what about the one at Microsoft.com. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771523(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal I've already seen that link a while ago, but it doesn't give much help. I **need** to customize it using blend, but I wasn't able to do so using this tool. Do you know how? Thanks.

Comment: **EVERYTHING** is editable in WPF. You just have to provide an adequate `DataTemplate`. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you how to do it.

Comment: @HighCore I agree with you, but I think the OP is more concerned about the tree list itself. I had problems with that myself. Ximbalimba Do you already have some project in blend? That's why you need it?

Comment: @eestein Yes I do. I already have done that in blend.

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this, maybe this will help you to get a north

```
<dxg:GridControl Name="GridName" Grid.Row="0">

<dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="ID" Header="ID" 
                    AllowEditing="false" 
                    AllowMoving="False" AllowGrouping="False" AllowSorting="False"
                    >
    </dxg:GridColumn>

    <dxg:GridColumn Name="Name" FieldName="Name" Header="Name" AllowEditing="true"
                    AllowMoving="False" AllowGrouping="False" AllowSorting="False" >
    </dxg:GridColumn>

</dxg:GridControl.Columns>

<dxg:GridControl.View>
    <dxg:TreeListView Name="TreePeople" AutoWidth="True"
        KeyFieldName="Id" ParentFieldName="ParentId"
        TreeDerivationMode="Selfreference"
        MultiSelectMode="Row" EditorShowMode="MouseUpFocused" ShowingEditor="TreePeople_ShowingEditor" CellValueChanging="TreePeople_CellValueChanging" >
        <dxg:TreeListView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
            <dxb:BarButtonItem BarItemName="btnAddRow"  />
            <dxb:BarButtonItem BarItemName="btnRemoveRow"  />
        </dxg:TreeListView.RowCellMenuCustomizations>
    </dxg:TreeListView>
</dxg:GridControl.View>

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <dxg:TreeListDragDropManager AllowDrag="True" AllowDrop="True" AllowAutoExpand="True" Drop="TreeListDragDropManager_Drop" Dropped="TreeListDragDropManager_Dropped" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

You need to iniciate a list before

```
public void constructor()
{
    try
    {
        IPeople cli = ProxyFactory.GetPeopleSvc();
        List<People> list = cli.GetClassification();

        if (list.count > 0)
        {
            ObservableCollection<People> tmp = new ObservableCollection<People>(list);
            GridName.ItemsSource = tmp;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Message.Show(e);
    }
}
```